# Magick::ImageMagickError: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `text' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4404

Tags: docker, imagemagick, rmagick

This error happened to me using Docker, but production on Heroku was fine.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:3.2.0

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -

RUN apt update -q && apt install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
    postgresql-client \
    nodejs \
    nano \
    libvips > /dev/null
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that you were getting an error in RMagick, and this was due to missing fonts on my system. Specifically, the default font that RMagick was trying to use was not available.

To fix the problem, you needed to install the gsfonts package, which contains several common fonts used in graphics applications.

To install gsfonts, you can use the following command on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install gsfonts
```